# How to debug and to fix syntax error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to combine these two lists to the string "an abu is smart".

```
list1=["a","ab","i","smar"]
list2=["t","s","u","n",]
def merge_list(list1, list2):
    merged=""
    b=-1
    result=''.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(list1,list2)])
    return result
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", in <module>
      merged=merge_list(list1,list2)
  File "main.py",in merge_list
      result=''.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(list1,list2)])
  File "main.py",in <listcomp>
      result=''.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(list1,list2)])
  TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How exactly are you calling this function?

Comment: If I just run the code you've shown and then `merge_list(list1, list2)`, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=["a","ab","i","smar"]
list2=["t","s","u","n"]
def merge_list(list1, list2):
    merged=""
    b=-1
    result=' '.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(list1,list2[::-1])])
    return result

print(merge_list(list1, list2))
```

Output

```
'an abu is smart'
```